How can I open Visual Studio Code settings in UI rather than JSON?
Every time I open settings it opens in JSON and there is no option to open in UI. This is a new install on a new Windows machine. Previously I didn't have any issue. Hoping for a simple solution if possible.
I can't see workbench.settings.editor at all in settings.json to change from JSON to UI

How are you opening the settings?
